# How to use events in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy

I am not sure if the event handling in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp is working correctly. In the example below, I integrated a derivative which should result in a cubic polynomial with three roots at x=-6, x=-2 and x=2. I set up an event function that returns y, which will be zero at those x-values. I expected to see three entries in the t_events attribute of the solution, but I only see one, even though it is clear the solution crosses the x-axis three times.

Am I doing something wrong here?

#### Reproducing code example:

```
def fprime(x, y):
    return 3 * x**2 + 12 * x - 4

def event(x, y):
    return y

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
sol = solve_ivp(fprime, (-8, 4), np.array([-120]), t_eval=np.linspace(-8, 4, 10), events=[event])
```

The code above results in:

```
message: 'The solver successfully reached the interval end.'
      nfev: 26
      njev: 0
       nlu: 0
       sol: None
    status: 0
   success: True
         t: array([-8.        , -6.66666667, -5.33333333, -4.        , -2.66666667,
        -1.33333333,  0.        ,  1.33333333,  2.66666667,  4.        ])
  t_events: [array([-6.])]
         y: array([[-120.        ,  -26.96296296,   16.2962963 ,   24.        ,
           10.37037037,  -10.37037037,  -24.        ,  -16.2962963 ,
           26.96296296,  120.        ]])
```

```

The problem is you can see from the sol.y array there should be three zeros (there are three sign changes), but only one event is recorded.

#### Scipy/Numpy/Python version information:

```
1.0.0 1.13.3 sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

[UPDATE]: if I use the optional max_step argument to solve_ivp, and make it small enough, then I see all three roots. It seems that the event functions are not called at the t_eval steps, but rather only on internal solver steps, which are far fewer than the t_eval steps, and which end up skipping some roots. That doesn't seem very useful, as you have to know how to set max_steps to avoid missing roots.

Comment: I feel like there should be an `append` somewhere. From `events=[event]` it looks like it is saving only the last return. By the way, why are you passing `y` to `fprime` and `x` to `event`. You are not using them.

Comment: those are all required signatures. That is not the problem here.

Answer (score 5):

> the event functions are not called at the `t_eval` steps, but rather only on internal solver steps

This is correct. After a new `(t, y)` pair [is found](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py#L484), the events are computed from them [and passed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py#L495) to `find_active_events` that will compare the signs of event-functions to the previous step.

`t_eval` is not used by the event computation at all, it is dealt with [later](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py#L513). So the sign changes that events see are those that you see in the output with `t_eval=None`, of which there is just one.

```
y: array([[-120.        , -110.49687882,  -35.93785936,   94.46893375,
     120.        ]])
```

Seems worth raising an issue on SciPy tracker; there are [a few open issues regarding `solve_ivp`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+solve_ivp+is%3Aopen), which is still pretty new.